# C: Loop through struct and concat to string

Tags: c, for-loop, concatenation, c-strings, strcat

I have `C` program with the following struct:

```
struct {      
    char *ext;
    char *filetype;
} extensions [] = {
    {"gif", "image/gif" },
    {"jpg", "image/jpg" },
    {"jpeg","image/jpeg"},
    {"png", "image/png" },
    {0,0}     
};
```

How do I create a function that returns a string that contains only the extensions separated by new lines? Basically this is what to be able to do this:

`printf("\nThe following extensions are supported:\n%s",GetExtensions());`

And have it output this:

```
The following extensions are supported:
.gif
.jpg
.jpeg
.png
```

I think I've got the looping part correct, but I'm not understanding how to concat each `ext` + `\n` to a string:

```
#include <leaving these off for brevity...>

struct {
    char *ext;
    char *filetype;
} extensions [] = {
    {"gif", "image/gif" },
    {"jpg", "image/jpg" },
    {"jpeg","image/jpeg"},
    {"png", "image/png" },
    {0,0}     
};

char *getExtensions(void) {
    char* exts;
    int i;
    for(i=0;extensions[i].ext != 0;i++){

        // What do I do here?? 

    }
    return exts;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    printf("\nThe following extensions are supported: \n%s",GetExtensions());
}
```

Comment: Why not just iterate over the `extensions` array, printing each `ext` value in turn. Rather than accumulating a string of extensions with newlines in it.

Comment: Is it homework ? Check getExtensions() vs GetExtensions(). And better use an array of char for exts:   `char exts[200];`
Then use sprintf() and strcat().

Comment: *"but I'm not understanding how to concat"* - When I search for "c concat" I find heaps of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Your struct
struct extensionInfo {
   char *ext;
   char *filetype;
};

struct extensionInfo extensions [] = {
   {"gif", "image/gif" },
   {"jpg", "image/jpg" },
   {"jpeg","image/jpeg"},
   {"png", "image/png" },
   {0,0}
};

int main(int argc, char **args, char **env) {
   char buffer[1024];
   struct extensionInfo *ext;

   // Initialize the buffer
   memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

   // Insert your first text.
   strncat(buffer, "The following extensions are supported:", sizeof(buffer) - 1);

   // Loop through your array and append everything
   for (ext = extensions; ext->ext != 0; ext++) {
      strncat(buffer, "\n", sizeof(buffer) - 1);
      strncat(buffer, ext->ext, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
   }

   // Show your result
   printf("%s\n", buffer);

   return 0;
}
```

Here is a commented example which works. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Because op wrote: "I'm not understanding how to concat each ext + \n to a string"

Answer (score 2):

It seems you mean the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct extension
{
    char *ext;
    char *filetype;
};

char * getExtensions( const struct extension a[] )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; a[i].ext != NULL; i++ )
    {
        n += strlen( a[i].ext ) + 1;
    }

    char *s = malloc( n + 1 );

    if ( s != NULL )
    {
        s[0] = '\0';

        for ( size_t i = 0; a[i].ext != NULL; i++ )
        {
            strcat( s, a[i].ext );
            strcat( s, "\n" );
        }
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct extension extensions [] = 
    {
        {"gif", "image/gif" },
        {"jpg", "image/jpg" },
        {"jpeg","image/jpeg"},
        {"png", "image/png" },
        { NULL, NULL }     
    };

    char *s = getExtensions( extensions ); 

    printf( "The following extensions are supported:\n%s", s );

    free( s );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The following extensions are supported:
gif
jpg
jpeg
png
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is what you wish. You can read the comments to grasp how it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct {
    char *ext;
    char *filetype;
} extensions [] = {
        {"gif", "image/gif" },
        {"jpg", "image/jpg" },
        {"jpeg","image/jpeg"},
        {"png", "image/png" },
        {0,0}
};

char *getExtensions(void) {
    size_t count = 0;
    // let's know how many characters are needed for all extensions
    for(int i = 0; extensions[i].ext != 0; ++i) {
        size_t j = 0;
        for (; extensions[i].ext[j] != 0; ++j) ;
        count += j + 1; // +1 for every newline
    }

    // +1 for null terminator
    char *str = calloc(count + 1, sizeof(char));

    // let's concatenate
    for(size_t i = 0; extensions[i].ext != 0; ++i) {
        strcat(str, extensions[i].ext);
        strcat(str, "\n");
    }

    return str;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char * const result = getExtensions();
    printf("\nThe following extensions are supported: \n%s", result);
    free(result);
}
```

Comment: Why write your own `strlen()`?

Comment: @jarmod I want the OP to show its logic. Built-in functions are good to use, but may not to learn. He can also write `strcat`'s whitebox by own by looking at it. Am I amiss?

Comment: It's not a big deal but I'm not sure that rewriting one of the most basic of library functions adds value. Higher levels of abstraction aid understanding, which is valuable to people asking programming questions on SO.

Comment: @jarmod When I was an undergraduate student, I liked such hints monumentally. It's not a great deal but helpful albeit being minute.